# Network packet capturing on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8-preview, winpcap

Unfortunately [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/) doesn't offer a version of their installer that runs on Windows 8. Since WinPcap uses a kernel-mode driver to capture network packets, it seems like a very terrible idea to force Windows 8 to use the Windows Vista / 7 driver.

Is there a build anywhere that offers a Windows 8 compatible driver or is there an alternative program for Windows 8 that offers this capability?

Comment: Surprising. There isn't any significant changes to the driver model to keep it from installing. . .

Comment: Actually, a lot of drivers I used to install on the Developer Preview I have just selected the Windows 7 compatibility mode. It's just so that the drivers don't support Windows 8 through their configuration/signing, but I really think nearly nothing has changed to the driver architecture. **Just try it**, you can always just go to Safe Mode to remove it if it breaks...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Forcing WinPcap to use *Windows 7 compatibility mode* worked for me on Windows 8 x64 consumer preview.

Comment: Seems to work for the Windows 8 x64 release preview as well, although a lot of outgoing IP headers are showing checksum errors.

Comment: Works for me too on Windows 8 RTM

Answer (score 1):

Can you try [Microsoft Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=4865)? However even here it supports upto Windows 7.

I would suggest installing Network Monitor or WinPcap in Windows 7 compatibility mode since Windows 8 driver model would be similar to Windows 7 driver model.

Comment: (quick update) Microsoft Network Monitor works on Windows 8, no updates for WinPcap yet.